# Access formatting value of conditional formatting in Power BI custom visual

Tags: conditional-formatting, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm new to Power BI custom visual development, following the Microsoft documentation, but I don't find it particularly helpful when it comes to conditional formatting.

I'm building up my visual using HTML elements, and I want to apply conditional formatting to the background color of the elements. I created a simplified example which is available here: https://github.com/DanielSzentimrey-Harrach/sampleVisual

In `settings.ts` I specified the instanceKind property on my color picker, so I can configure conditional formatting:

```js
class DataPointCardSettings extends FormattingSettingsCard {
    defaultColor = new formattingSettings.ColorPicker({
        name: "defaultColor",
        displayName: "Default color",
        value: { value: "" },
        instanceKind: powerbi.VisualEnumerationInstanceKinds.ConstantOrRule
    });

    name: string = "dataPoint";
    displayName: string = "Data colors";
    slices: Array<FormattingSettingsSlice> = [this.defaultColor];
}
```

In my `visual.ts` I simply iterate through the input values, and display the category name within a span. I use the measure value to set the width of the span. (This simple logic is just for the sake of this example.):

```js
public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
    this.formattingSettings = this.formattingSettingsService.populateFormattingSettingsModel(VisualFormattingSettingsModel, options.dataViews[0]);
    
    const dataView: powerbi.DataView = options.dataViews[0];
    const categoricalMapping = dataView.categorical;

    this.target.innerHTML = "";

    for (let i=0; i < categoricalMapping.categories[0].values.length; i++) {
        const span: HTMLElement = document.createElement("span");
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode(categoricalMapping.categories[0].values[i].toString()));
        span.style.width = 50 * +categoricalMapping.values[0].values[i].toString() + "px";
        span.style.backgroundColor = this.formattingSettings.dataPointCard.defaultColor.value.value;
        this.target.appendChild(span);
    }
}
```

I know that the second to last line (`span.style.backgroundColor...`) is not right, but I don't know how to access the specific result of the conditional formatting for each individual item.

In Power BI, I have the following:

- Input data
  [image]
- Data mapping
  [image]
- Formatting settings
  [image]

Notice how I'm picking the **first** value from the Color column, which is "blue" for Cat3.

After this, in my visual all the spans are colored blue.
[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.